# URLRequest gets HTTP error 502 and "connection reset by peer"

Tags: swift3

Got these errors with this code:

```
        if let url = URL(string: "<valid web service url string>") {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("Basic \(base64Authorization)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
```

The same code returns no error with Xcode 7.3 but errors in Xcode 8 after converting to Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because of the Swift 3 proposal [SE-0054](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md).

base64Authorization was declared this way:

```
    static var base64Authorization:String! {
    get {
        if base64Auth == nil {
            let keyString = "<my key string>"
            let plainTextData = keyString.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) as Data!
            base64Auth = plainTextData!.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithLineFeed) as String!
        }

        return base64Auth
    }
}
```

base64Authorization returned an Optional which messed up the "Basic \(base64Authorization)" HTTP setting.

This declaration of base64Authorization fixed the problem:

```
    static var base64Authorization:String {
    get {
        if base64Auth == nil {
            let keyString = "<my key string>"
            let plainTextData = keyString.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) as Data!
            base64Auth = plainTextData!.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithLineFeed) as String
        }

        return base64Auth!
    }
}
```